# Problem with ExpressJS adding route name to static file paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a web app based on express and ejs.

I have two routes index and article.

While the static files such as stylesheets and scripts are served as expected at index route, the article route does not serve the scripts correctly.

```
//app.js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var articleRouter = require('./routes/article');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/article', articleRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- The above 4 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Core Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ##### Header Area Start ##### -->
    <header class="header-area">
      <!-- Navbar Area -->
      <div class="newspaper-main-menu top-header-area" id="">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="top-header-content d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="logo">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="136px" height="53.429px" viewBox="0 0 136 53.429" enable-background="new 0 0 136 53.429" xml:space="preserve">
                                            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M7.538,14.257c0.268-1.225,0.852-2.194,1.753-2.903c0.901-0.709,2.021-1.063,3.363-1.063  c1.188,0,2.156,0.24,2.904,0.718c0.747,0.48,1.274,1.543,1.58,3.191l4.369,22.65h0.115l4.772-22.593  c0.268-1.225,0.862-2.194,1.782-2.903s1.897-1.063,2.932-1.063c1.035,0,1.859,0.355,2.472,1.063c0.612,0.71,0.786,1.677,0.517,2.903  l-7.357,34.607c-0.308,1.38-0.92,2.444-1.84,3.191c-0.92,0.747-1.897,1.122-2.932,1.122c-1.572,0-2.712-0.25-3.421-0.747  c-0.71-0.497-1.198-1.552-1.466-3.162l-4.254-22.995h-0.115L7.826,49.21c-0.269,1.226-0.862,2.195-1.782,2.903  c-0.92,0.708-1.897,1.064-2.932,1.064s-1.859-0.355-2.472-1.064s-0.786-1.676-0.517-2.903L7.538,14.257z M36.915,27.019  c0.805-3.794,1.801-6.813,2.989-9.055c1.187-2.242,2.5-3.948,3.937-5.116c1.437-1.169,2.951-1.925,4.542-2.27  s3.191-0.517,4.801-0.517c1.61,0,3.133,0.172,4.57,0.517c1.437,0.345,2.625,1.102,3.564,2.27c0.939,1.17,1.524,2.874,1.754,5.116  s-0.057,5.26-0.862,9.055l-1.84,8.738c-0.843,3.909-1.84,7.023-2.989,9.341c-1.15,2.32-2.425,4.092-3.823,5.317  c-1.4,1.227-2.914,2.031-4.542,2.415c-1.63,0.382-3.325,0.575-5.088,0.575c-1.802,0-3.43-0.193-4.886-0.575  c-1.457-0.383-2.616-1.187-3.479-2.415c-0.862-1.226-1.371-2.998-1.523-5.317c-0.153-2.319,0.191-5.432,1.035-9.341L36.915,27.019z   M43.123,35.758c-0.538,2.529-0.872,4.552-1.007,6.064c-0.134,1.514-0.106,2.683,0.086,3.507c0.192,0.825,0.556,1.361,1.092,1.61  c0.537,0.25,1.188,0.373,1.955,0.373s1.466-0.124,2.099-0.373c0.632-0.249,1.226-0.785,1.782-1.61  c0.555-0.824,1.092-1.993,1.61-3.507c0.517-1.513,1.044-3.535,1.58-6.064l1.84-8.738c0.46-2.223,0.747-4.043,0.862-5.461  c0.115-1.418,0.067-2.529-0.143-3.334c-0.211-0.805-0.575-1.35-1.092-1.639c-0.517-0.287-1.16-0.431-1.926-0.431  c-0.768,0-1.466,0.143-2.099,0.431c-0.632,0.287-1.226,0.834-1.782,1.639c-0.556,0.805-1.083,1.916-1.58,3.334  c-0.498,1.418-0.977,3.238-1.437,5.461L43.123,35.758z M45.308,3.852c0.192-1.072,0.747-1.983,1.667-2.731  C47.894,0.374,48.891,0,49.965,0c1.072,0,1.897,0.374,2.472,1.121c0.575,0.747,0.767,1.658,0.575,2.731  c-0.23,1.073-0.805,1.983-1.725,2.731c-0.92,0.747-1.917,1.121-2.989,1.121c-1.073,0-1.897-0.373-2.472-1.121  C45.25,5.835,45.077,4.925,45.308,3.852z M56.001,3.852c0.191-1.072,0.747-1.983,1.667-2.731C58.587,0.374,59.583,0,60.657,0  c1.072,0,1.897,0.374,2.472,1.121c0.575,0.747,0.767,1.658,0.575,2.731c-0.23,1.073-0.805,1.983-1.725,2.731  c-0.92,0.747-1.917,1.121-2.989,1.121c-1.073,0-1.897-0.373-2.472-1.121C55.942,5.835,55.771,4.925,56.001,3.852z M70.429,14.257  c0.268-1.225,0.852-2.194,1.753-2.903c0.901-0.709,2.021-1.063,3.363-1.063c1.188,0,2.156,0.24,2.904,0.718  c0.747,0.48,1.274,1.543,1.58,3.191l4.369,22.65h0.115l4.772-22.593c0.268-1.225,0.862-2.194,1.782-2.903s1.897-1.063,2.932-1.063  c1.035,0,1.859,0.355,2.472,1.063c0.612,0.71,0.786,1.677,0.517,2.903L89.63,48.865c-0.308,1.38-0.92,2.444-1.84,3.191  c-0.92,0.747-1.897,1.122-2.932,1.122c-1.572,0-2.712-0.25-3.421-0.747c-0.71-0.497-1.198-1.552-1.466-3.162l-4.254-22.995h-0.115  L70.717,49.21c-0.269,1.226-0.862,2.195-1.782,2.903c-0.92,0.708-1.897,1.064-2.932,1.064c-1.035,0-1.859-0.355-2.472-1.064  c-0.613-0.709-0.786-1.676-0.517-2.903L70.429,14.257z M94.458,49.824c0.193-0.882,0.662-1.626,1.406-2.233  c0.744-0.606,1.557-0.91,2.44-0.91s1.557,0.304,2.026,0.91c0.468,0.607,0.606,1.35,0.414,2.233s-0.655,1.627-1.386,2.233  c-0.73,0.606-1.537,0.91-2.419,0.91c-0.882,0-1.564-0.304-2.046-0.91C94.41,51.451,94.265,50.706,94.458,49.824z M119.393,47.632  c-0.165,0.717-0.262,1.365-0.289,1.943c-0.028,0.579-0.083,1.048-0.165,1.406c-0.138,0.662-0.462,1.158-0.971,1.489  c-0.51,0.331-1.165,0.496-1.965,0.496c-0.69,0-1.255-0.201-1.695-0.6c-0.442-0.399-0.552-1.151-0.331-2.253l-0.083,0.041  c-0.69,1.02-1.503,1.744-2.44,2.17c-0.938,0.427-1.861,0.641-2.771,0.641c-0.744,0-1.413-0.118-2.006-0.352  c-0.593-0.234-1.069-0.592-1.426-1.075c-0.359-0.482-0.586-1.102-0.683-1.861c-0.097-0.757-0.035-1.66,0.187-2.709  c0.358-1.709,0.916-3.08,1.675-4.115c0.757-1.034,1.881-1.908,3.37-2.626l5.003-2.357c1.185-0.551,1.888-1.336,2.109-2.357  c0.138-0.606,0.083-1.131-0.165-1.571s-0.69-0.662-1.323-0.662c-0.882,0-1.53,0.221-1.944,0.662  c-0.414,0.442-0.773,1.103-1.075,1.985c-0.165,0.496-0.496,0.889-0.992,1.178c-0.496,0.289-1.075,0.435-1.737,0.435  c-0.275,0-0.566-0.034-0.868-0.104c-0.304-0.069-0.566-0.187-0.786-0.352s-0.392-0.378-0.516-0.641  c-0.124-0.261-0.145-0.585-0.063-0.971c0.193-0.965,0.558-1.819,1.095-2.564c0.538-0.744,1.178-1.365,1.922-1.861  c0.744-0.496,1.571-0.875,2.481-1.138c0.91-0.261,1.847-0.392,2.812-0.392c1.681,0,2.977,0.172,3.887,0.516  c0.91,0.345,1.557,0.821,1.944,1.427c0.386,0.607,0.572,1.31,0.559,2.109c-0.014,0.8-0.117,1.654-0.311,2.564L119.393,47.632z   M115.796,40.851l-2.068,1.241c-0.634,0.386-1.158,0.737-1.571,1.054s-0.751,0.634-1.013,0.951c-0.262,0.318-0.462,0.656-0.6,1.014  s-0.262,0.773-0.372,1.241c-0.165,0.854-0.138,1.51,0.083,1.964c0.22,0.455,0.606,0.683,1.158,0.683  c0.827,0,1.557-0.399,2.192-1.199c0.633-0.799,1.075-1.792,1.323-2.977L115.796,40.851z M127.125,33.821h-0.537  c-0.744,0-1.276-0.137-1.593-0.414c-0.317-0.275-0.406-0.757-0.269-1.447c0.138-0.716,0.428-1.213,0.868-1.489  c0.441-0.275,1.034-0.414,1.778-0.414h0.538l0.827-3.846c0.22-1.047,0.606-1.812,1.157-2.294c0.552-0.482,1.213-0.723,1.986-0.723  c0.772,0,1.336,0.241,1.695,0.723c0.357,0.483,0.428,1.248,0.207,2.294l-0.827,3.846h1.158c0.743,0,1.268,0.138,1.571,0.414  c0.304,0.275,0.386,0.773,0.248,1.489c-0.138,0.69-0.421,1.172-0.848,1.447c-0.428,0.275-1.013,0.414-1.757,0.414h-1.158  l-2.811,13.15c-0.111,0.469-0.111,0.834,0,1.095c0.109,0.262,0.454,0.421,1.033,0.476c0.579,0.027,1.007,0.165,1.282,0.414  c0.274,0.248,0.344,0.703,0.207,1.365c-0.194,0.854-0.586,1.461-1.179,1.819s-1.426,0.538-2.501,0.538  c-0.965,0-1.751-0.118-2.357-0.352c-0.607-0.234-1.069-0.545-1.386-0.93c-0.317-0.385-0.503-0.827-0.558-1.323  c-0.056-0.496-0.028-1.007,0.083-1.53L127.125,33.821z"/>
                                        </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="noen-header">
                  <h1 onClick="scrollToItem(3)">Overview</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- ##### Header Area End ##### -->

    <!-- ##### Featured Post Area Start ##### -->
    <div class="featured-post-area">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
            <%- news_item %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function goBackToOverview() {
      location.href = '/';
    }
  </script>

  <!-- ##### All Javascript Files ##### -->
  <!-- jQuery-2.2.4 js -->
  <script src="javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper js -->
  <script src="javascripts/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap js -->
  <script src="javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- All Plugins js -->
  <script src="javascripts/plugins.js"></script>
  <!-- Active js -->
  <script src="javascripts/active.js"></script>
</html>
```

It says: `Loading failed for the <script> with the source "http://localhost:3000/article/javascripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js".`

I think that the problem is that the route name (article) is added to the path. What's your opinion/solution?

Comment: Maybe add appropriate ```..``` in your path for loading the scripts?

Comment: @VedantBang oh you are right. :)